# How do I create a Flow with a different input and output types for use inside of a graph?

Tags: akka-stream

I am making a custom sink by building a graph on the inside. Here is a broad simplification of my code to demonstrate my question:

```
def mySink: Sink[Int, Unit] = Sink() { implicit builder =>

    val entrance = builder.add(Flow[Int].buffer(500, OverflowStrategy.backpressure))
    val toString = builder.add(Flow[Int, String, Unit].map(_.toString))
    val printSink = builder.add(Sink.foreach(elem => println(elem)))

    builder.addEdge(entrance.out, toString.in)
    builder.addEdge(toString.out, printSink.in)

    entrance.in
}
```

The problem I am having is that while it is valid to create a Flow with the same input/output types with only a single type argument and no value argument like: `Flow[Int]` (which is all over the documentation) it is not valid to only supply two type parameters and zero value parameters.

According to the [reference documentation for the Flow object](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC2/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow$) the `apply` method I am looking for is defined as

```
def apply[I, O]()(block: (Builder[Unit]) ⇒ (Inlet[I], Outlet[O])): Flow[I, O, Unit]
```

and says

> Creates a Flow by passing a FlowGraph.Builder to the given create function.
>
> The create function is expected to return a pair of Inlet and Outlet which correspond to the created Flows input and output ports.

It seems like I need to deal with another level of graph builders when I am trying to make what I think is a very simple flow. Is there an easier and more concise way to create a Flow that changes the type of it's input and output that doesn't require messing with it's inside ports? If this is the right way to approach this problem, what would a solution look like?

BONUS: Why is it easy to make a Flow that doesn't change the type of its input from it's output?

Comment: "it is not valid to only supply two type parameters and zero value parameters" What would the semantics be of these kind of flows? Are you thinking of a shorter form of `Flow[Int].map(_.toString)`?

Comment: My understanding is that `Flow[Int].map(_.toString)` is invalid because `Flow[Int]` indicates a flow from `Int` to `Int`. However the type of your map function (`_.toString`) is `Int => String`. Is this incorrect? (Your comment and looking at the docs with fresh eyes lead me to suspect that I am incorrect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify both the input and the output type of a flow, you indeed need to use the apply method you found in the documentation. Using it, though, is done pretty much exactly the same as you already did.

```
Flow[String, Message]() { implicit b =>
  import FlowGraph.Implicits._

  val reverseString = b.add(Flow[String].map[String] { msg => msg.reverse })
  val mapStringToMsg = b.add(Flow[String].map[Message]( x => TextMessage.Strict(x)))

  // connect the graph
  reverseString ~> mapStringToMsg

  // expose ports
  (reverseString.inlet, mapStringToMsg.outlet)
}
```

Instead of just returning the inlet, you return a tuple, with the inlet and the outlet. This flow can now we used (for instance inside another builder, or directly with runWith) with a specific Source or Sink.

Comment: This whole answer is good but the part I was specifically looking for is `Flow[String].map[Message]( x => TextMessage.Strict(x))`. Thanks!